# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setShowActionsInCompactView: action 1 out of bounds (max 0)

Tags: android, media-player, android-notifications, illegalstateexception

I am building media style notification for a radio app in android. Here's my code for notification :

```
NotificationCompat.Action action = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(imgNotificationAction, "playPause", pendingIntent).build();
    //create new notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setShowWhen(false)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2))
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
            //.setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_headset)
            .setContentText(radioName)
            .setContentTitle("Igala Radio presents")
            .setContentInfo("Igala language radio")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .addAction(action);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

But I get following exception in Log cat :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setShowActionsInCompactView: action 1 out of bounds (max 0)
                                                                 at android.app.Notification$MediaStyle.makeMediaContentView(Notification.java:4493)
                                                                 at android.app.Notification$MediaStyle.populateContentView(Notification.java:4427)
                                                                 at android.app.Notification$Style.buildStyled(Notification.java:3894)
                                                                 at android.app.Notification$MediaStyle.buildStyled(Notification.java:4415)
                                                                 at android.app.Notification$Builder.build(Notification.java:3638)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatApi21$Builder.build(NotificationCompatApi21.java:132)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat$LollipopExtender.build(NotificationCompat.java:484)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImplApi21.build(NotificationCompat.java:827)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder.build(NotificationCompat.java:1744)
                                                                 at com.radio.igala.Service.PlayService.buildNotification(PlayService.java:253)
                                                                 at com.radio.igala.Service.PlayService.onStartCommand(PlayService.java:127)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3216)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:188) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1628) 
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210) 
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5839) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1113) 
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:879)
```

I am wondering why it states **action 1 out of bounds (max 0)**. Does that mean I can't add any action in it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that error is happening because you are defining the actions (`addAction()`) after `setShowActionsInCompactView()`.

This way, you are trying to `setShowActionsInCompactView` when `notificationBuilder` has no actions yet. In another words, its internal array has 0 elements (Max 0)

Can you try something like:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .addAction(action)
        ...
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())
                .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2))
        ....;
```

**Edit**

Another error I found is:

You are creating only one action:

```
NotificationCompat.Action action = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(imgNotificationAction, "playPause", pendingIntent).build();
```

But here, you are setting 3 actions:

```
.setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2))
```

The number of actions `setShowActionsInCompactView()` should match with the number of actions you added via `addAction()`.

You can add more actions (create new actions and call `addAction()` again or send only one argument to `setShowActionsInCompactView()`

Comment: Did exactly what you said. Still same exception :|

Comment: @MoFaizanShaikh I updated my answer. Could you please double check

Comment: oh but I want to add only one action. what should I do?

Comment: use .setShowActionsInCompactView(0) instead of .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2)

Comment: Thank you that did the job :). Now, there arise another problem :|. when I start music within app it shows notification, but when I pause the music from notification and then play it again, then the notification disappears

Comment: U helped alot. can you answer this plz?

Answer (score 0):

```
.setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2))
```

did the trick for me. @WormH0le

> @WormH0le i love you.